# Mapeamento EF com classes genéricas

Tags: c#, entity-framework

tenho um projeto que utilizava NHibernate com uma estrutura de classes genéricas/abstratas que eram mapeadas sem problemas. o problema é que fui obrigado a migrar pro Entity Framework e agora estou perdido em como fazer o mapeamento.

```
public abstract class CadastroMestre
{
    public virtual Int32 Identificador { get; set; }
    public virtual String Descricao { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MestreDetalhe : CadastroMestre
{
    public virtual CadastroMestre Mestre { get; set; }
    public virtual CadastroMestre Detalhe { get; set; }
}

public abstract class CadastroMestreLista : CadastroMestre
{
    public virtual IList<MestreDetalhe> Detalhes { get; set; }
}

public class TipoDocumento : CadastroMestre
{
}

public class TipoPessoa : CadastroMestreLista
{
}

public class RelacionamentoTipoPessoaTipoDocumento : MestreDetalhe
{
    public virtual Boolean Obrigatorio { get; set; }

    public RelacionamentoTipoPessoaTipoDocumento()
    {
        Mestre = new TipoPessoa();
        Detalhe = new TipoDocumento();
    }
}
```

estou com problemas em mapear esses objetos com seus nomes corretos TipoDocumentos, TipoPessoa e RelacionamentoTipoPessoaTipoDocumento. estes são apenas um exemplo, pois existem varios outros objetos utilizando as mesmas classes.

Comment: Você quer que cada classe represente uma tabela no banco? ou apenas a implementação final de cada entidade?

Comment: preciso mapear as classes TipoPessoa, TipoDocumento e RelacionamentoTipoPessoaTipoDocumento. tipo documento é tranquilo. o problema é mapear Detalhes(que está em CadastroMestreLista) na classe TipoPessoa, que é uma lista de RelacionamentoTipoPessoaTipoDocumento na propriedade mestre e mapear a classe RelacionamentoTipoPessoaTipoDocumento.

Comment: como mapeava no NHibernate:

Detalhes de TipoPessoa:
`code`    <bag name="Detalhes" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
      <key column="RPD_MESTRE" />
      <one-to-many class="Framework.Modelo.Entidade.Cadastro.RelacionamentoTipoPessoaTipoDocumento"/>
    </bag>
`code`

RelacionamentoTipoPessoaTipoDocumento:
`code`    <many-to-one name="Mestre" column="RPD_MESTRE" class="Framework.Modelo.Entidade.Cadastro.TipoPessoa" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Detalhe" column="RPD_DETALHE" class="Framework.Modelo.Entidade.Cadastro.TipoDocumento" not-null="true" />`code`